# how transactional support is provided in Web Services technology

Tags: web-services, service, transactions, soa

I am confused about the Transactional Support in Web service
is its the execution of different pieces together
or its the Status Code after the Execution is been done

in other words I wanted to know  how transactional support is provided in Web Services technology

Comment: Voting to close this question as too broad, but research [WS-Transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Transaction).

Comment: Wrapping multiple service calls in a transaction is generally best avoided if possible. The out-of-process nature of service calls are kind of anathema to ACID. It would be better if at all possible to all a single service which performs multiple tasks which you can call once.